# getting user location and creating map not in sync

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

The below code is getting the user current location and creating a mapbox map.
problem is that the mapbox map is being created before the users location is obtain.
How may I slow or sync this process?
Thank you in advance,

```
  import UIKit
  import CoreLocation
  import MapboxGL

 class AViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   var manager:CLLocationManager!
   var userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 25.776243, longitude: -80.136509)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("inside viewdidload")
    self.getUserLocation()
}//eom

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("inside viewdidappear")
   self.createMapBoxMap()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*** MapBox Functions ************************************************************************/
    /*Create preliminary map */
    func createMapBoxMap(){
        // set your access token
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, accessToken: "pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFya2ZhZGVyIiwiYSI6IlplVDhfR3MifQ.pPEz732qS8g0WEScdItakg")

        mapView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

        // set the map's center coordinate
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude),
            zoomLevel: 13, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        //showing the user location on map - blue dot
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }//eom


/*** location Functions ************************************************************************/
    /*getting user current location*/
    func getUserLocation(){
        self.manager = CLLocationManager()
        self.manager.delegate = self
        self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }//eom

    /*location manager 'didUpdateLocations' function */
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation() //stop getting user location
        println(locations)

        self.userLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

    }//eom

    /* errors occurred */
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }//eom
```

}//eoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location manager is running asynchronously (expected behavior), which means that it returns immediately and finishes creating the map as soon as the create map box method is called. However, it doesn't mean that the map has gotten a location yet. I'm thinking that the best way to implement this would be to move `self.createMapBoxMap()` to inside `didUpdateLocations` and try that. From my experience, you want the creation of your view to happen in a callback from an asynchronous method like this. You might want to have some type of loading view though, because the user will be confused at first.

Comment: I try by moving the self.createMapBoxMap() inside the viewDidLoad. but the map is still being created prior the user location being obtain. @rb612

Comment: @LuAndre did you add it after self.userLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation?

Comment: I moved it inside the location manager and now is working.  I had it inside the viewdidload but not inside the location manager function. How different will that be? sorry i am new to IOS.

Comment: @LuAndre no problem! Glad to hear you got it working.  Did you add it to didUpdateLocations to get it to work? The reason why is because before, it would go like this: "okay, I'm going to try and get the user's location but while I'm doing that, I'm going to make the map." So it was using the old value in your CLLocation variable because the map was being created too soon. Now, it'll create only after you have the location stored.

Comment: @LuAndre as an advanced step, once you start to learn more about Grand Central Dispatch and multithreading, take a look at how you can add a callback to this code to update locations.